# Http 404 error after publishing a web application onto web server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, webserver

I have a web application which is working good on my local system. I have used Visual studio one-click publish method to deploy it to the server. The publish shows successful but when I try to browse the web site with http:\servername\application, it is giving me HTTP 404 web page not found error message.

Is it any type of setting in IIS that I am missing or please let me know how can I fix this and make the application run from the server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the .aspx or .html page which ever you are using as default page..after the url you have given..and see if the problem is still there

Comment: IIS 7, the windows version is Windows server 2008 R2

Comment: Three things..
1. Make sure the site you are working here is the root directory.

2. Add MIME type if not added.

3. Go through this https://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/verbs

if u r missing the verb.

Comment: 1. yes it is under root directory 2.what is this MIME type? (I am a starter with this deployment process so not sure what it is)3. Is it a command line?

Comment: Go through this..and add proper MIME type

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: There is also a sharepoint's application server running from the same web server (if that stops other normal asp.net web applications from VS or something?)